# What is a variable defined inside class definition without decorator @ or @@?

Tags: ruby, class, local-variables

In Ruby, such code is legal:

```
class Aclass
  m = 1
end
```

but semantically speaking, what will `m` be, and how is it supposed to be accessed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`m` is just a local variable. It can only be accessed from within the class definition. It could be used to bootstrap the class for instance, but it can't be accessed from anywhere else.

For example:

```
class Aclass

  m=1
  puts "m is #{m}"

end
```

That code would be run only once, when you require the file containing that class. This is somewhat analogous to Java's [static initialisation blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: it seems to have a somehow weird lifetime though.

have been using `ObjectSpace.define_finalizer` to announce its destruction, and the destruction comes at end of whole program.

however after `end` of `class`, even a monkey patch cannot access it.





at least it can be used to announce a class's being required.

Comment: "it can be accessed from anywhere else" -> "it **can't** be accessed from anywhere else"?

Comment: @jokester All objects behaves like that. If you don't call `GC.start` (to run the garbage collector) all objects will be destructed at end of program.

Comment: @LBg thanks, it is astonishing to me. However even explicitly called `GC.start` beforehand, m did not get recycled until end of program. Is is possible to enforce its execution, so that we may clarify its lifetime?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the semantic term for `m` is, but it's just a regular variable in the scope of the class.  You won't be able to access it outside of the class though (not even in the methods defined in the class).

Comment: They are called *local variables* in Ruby, and in pretty much every other programming language as well. Java calls them *local fields*, I believe.